# How is the performance of Jackson ObjectMapper as static field in a singleton class?

Tags: spring, jackson, singleton, jackson-databind

I am thinking of using Jackson ObjectMapper for serializing/deserializing data for my production project.

Right now I have declared ObjectMapper as a `static` field in a singleton class (Spring `Component`) having `serialize` and `deserialize` methods. Both these method will use this static variable.
I am aware that the Jackson ObjectMapper is thread safe but I want to know will there be any performance issues observed when these methods are called multiple (of the order thousands) times concurrently?

I read it somewhere that object serialization is a heavy weight
and lengthy operation and there can be synchronization delays since the incoming threads can be locked at a given time waiting for the owner of the lock to complete the serialization/deserialization of JSON. Is it true?

The reason I don't want to initialize a new instance of `ObjectMapper` in each of serialize/deserialize methods is because it is a costly operation.

```
@Component
public class converter {

    private static final ObjectMapper OBJECTMAPPER = new ObjectMapper().configure(
        DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false).setSerializationInclusion(
                JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);

    public String serialize(Object value) {
        OBJECTMAPPER.writeValueAsString(...)
        ...
    }   
    public Object deserialize(String value) {
        OBJECTMAPPER.readValue(...)
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are really very concern of the performance , you can consider to further use  `ObjectReader`/`ObjectWriter` over `ObjectMapper` . Also consider using `Afterburner` Jackson module.

Comment: The fact that it's thread-safe doesn't mean it uses locks. It is *designed* to be used concurrently.